# How to get address by selected city google maps api?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps

How can I get some place like street, avenue etc in selected city?
I found solution in docs with radius.

```
searchOptions={
  location: new google.maps.LatLng(59.9342802, 30.335098600000038),
  radius: 2000,
  types: ['address'],
}
```

But in every city a radius is different and it is very not a universal way.

I want to select city in first input and then write address and see suggested addresses only in selected city in second input. Please help me. If this is important I use `ReactJS` and plugin `react-places-autocomplete`.

Answer (score 0):

Find out some decision. Maybe for someone it will be useful.

1. Search address.
   `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=Донецк Украина`
2. Then its data by place_id
   `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=ChIJ7aVxnOTHwoARxKIntFtakKo`
3. Get lat, lng, city, country and insert further
   `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?location=48.00621599999999,37.8450388&types=(cities)&input=Donetsk`